# Java 17 - GraalVM - Spring Boot 3 - Failing with unreachable Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm

I have build the graalvm code, but it is failing with this execution error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Code that was considered unreachable by closed-world analysis was reached.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:92)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.snippets.SnippetRuntime.unsupportedFeature(SnippetRuntime.java:173)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.io.BufferedReader.close(BufferedReader.java:522)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.parse(ServiceLoader.java:1178)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1213)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
        at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.findServiceProviders(LoggerFactory.java:114)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:178)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:185)
        at com.quizroulette.LegacyServer.LegacyServerApplication.main(LegacyServerApplication.java:10)
```

Here is the PR: https://github.com/quiz-roulette/legacy-service/pull/1

Which I am trying to build.

[Some of the Github Issues say it is resolved in Java 21](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5778#issuecomment-1727797954). Is it worth I upgrade to Java 21 directly?

Comment: I compiled and rand the native executable. did not get the exception when I hit to localhost:8080 I got 404 but no UnsupportedFeatureError, I put the screen shot  [here](https://github.com/quiz-roulette/legacy-service/pull/1#issuecomment-1836824825)

Comment: Thanks Oz. I updated to Java 21. And it worked.